# Mod_Rewrite Rule to remove .php file extensions on localhost

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm currently working on a site on my local machine (Wamp) and I've been trying clean up my urls with htaccess, but I can't seen to get it to work..I don't know much (anything really) about Apache.

Important?:

- I'm using WAMP Server
- I Have turned on Mod_rewrite
- my website url: **localhost/myapp1/**......my site is in this directory

Can you please help me with the correct code to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess to remove .PHP extension (Godaddy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/htaccess-to-remove-php-extension-godaddy)

Answer (score 3):

In your **myapp1** directory add these rules to the htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myapp1/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this still isn't working! Not sure if there is a problem with WAMP!